# Mongoose ODM on Index could not get any response in client application

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Currently i am working on Express with Mongoose ODM to build a RESTful API for my mobile app. In my Mongoose Schema i have a title: **Index** field. I follow Mongoose [Unique Index  Validation Document](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) to create Unique Document in MongoDB, **bellow is my code**

### Mongoose Schema

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;


var CategorySchema = new Schema({

    title: { type: String, required: true, index: true, unique: true },
    details: { type: String, required: false },
    thumbnail: { type: String, required: false },
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    modified: { type: Date, default: Date.now }

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);
```

### Express Code

```js
var express = require('express');
var routes  = express.Router();

var Category = require('./models/category.model');

routes.route('/categories')
  .post(function(req, res) {

    Category.on('index', function(error) {

        if(error) {
            res.send(error);
        }

        Category.create({ title: req.body.title, details: req.body.details, 
          thumbnail: req.body.thumbnail }, function(error) {
            if(error) {
                res.send(error);
            }

            res.json({ message: 'Category was save successfully..!' });
        });
    });

});
```

### Problem:

Now my problem is that, when i send a **POST** request to my API `http://localhost:3000/api/v1.0/categories.` It will not send any response to my client application. This will not show any Warning or Error in server console.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point in having

```
Category.on('index', function(error) {
    if(error) {
        res.send(error);
    }
 }
```

there. Do you want to listen to the index event inside a controller function? Probably not.

You can move

```
Category.create({ title: req.body.title, details: req.body.details, 
  thumbnail: req.body.thumbnail }, function(error) {
    if(error) {
        res.send(error);
    }

    res.json({ message: 'Category was save successfully..!' });
});
```

out of it. You should also make sure you return after sending a response, otherwise you might end up sending several responses. Inside `if(error)` you do a `res.send(error)` but it will continue to the `res.json()` later.

So if the rest of your code is correct then this might work:

```
var express = require('express');
var routes  = express.Router();

var Category = require('./models/category.model');

routes.route('/categories').post(function(req, res) {
    Category.create({ 
      title: req.body.title,
      details: req.body.details, 
      thumbnail: req.body.thumbnail 
    }, function(error) {
        if(error) {
            return res.status(500).json(error);
        }

        return res.status(201).json({ message: 'Category was save successfully..!' });
    });
});
```

You will get an error message if you break the unique constraint for *title*. This will happen when you do the create. You have to restart the app before the unique constraint starts working.